# Why was wget.exe detected as a virus?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, cygwin, wget

I installed Cygwin on Windows 7 and it installed properly.
I selected various packages; including curl and wget.

Yet, my anti-virus (AVG 2011) detected it as malware, with 4 red bars and put it into the Virus Vault!

I then sent the suspected file to Kaspersky's filescanner online but it came back as clean from their online scan

I then proceeded to uninstall Cygwin and restart Windows; now it's left me a bit wary of using it on Windows 7 again for fear of a virus.

Is wget always detected as a virus, and should I always be this cautious with cygwin?

Is there much difference between the Windows versions of wget and the Linux/unix ones?
Some sources I read suggested I download the older wget versions to reduce the risk of virus; the Wget version in question that was detected as a virus was the latest one.

What's the best way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Either you downloaded a copy with malware embedded or you have found a false-positive. Either way this is a question for [AVG - Customer Support](http://www.avg.com/us-en/support). It doesn't fit in with ["What kind of questions can I ask here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and I vote to close.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're a programmer, you could download and read [the source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/) and once you're satisfied that the code is malware free build and install it!

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded wget from an official Cygwin repository, there's nearly no chance of a virus.

I think AVG is a little bit overzealous, and since wget is used to download data from the internet, it is recognized as a malware.

Nothing to be afraid about, you can ignore the problem I think.

You should maybe just contact the AVG team to make them aware of the situation.

Comment: -1 for "Nothing to be afraid about, you can ignore the problem I think." What is the point in installing anti-virus software if you're going to ignore it?

Comment: @Johnsyweb This sentence is strongly related to "official Cygwin repository" and "overzealous". The point of an AV software is to alert the user, once you're pretty confident it was a false positive, you can stop to worry. wget is a well-known software, Cygwin also, all packages are signed.

Comment: Every Virus scanner will only work with support from **Brain 1.0**.